# How to send Contact Us HTML Page details by email

Tags: javascript, html, email

I need help with someone checking this code and guiding me to the next steps to get the Contact Us page details like Full Name, Email, Subject, Text via email. I would  like to know what I need to change in the below code to get it working. What options do i have?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Contact Us</title>
    <script>
        function clickHere() {
            var name = document.getElementById("textName");
            var namevalue = name.value;
            var email = document.getElementById("emailName");
            var emailvalue = email.value;
            var subject = document.getElementById("subjectName");
            var subjectvalue = subject.value;
            var text = document.getElementById("importantName");
            var textvalue = text.value;
            var regName = /^[a-zA-Z]+ [a-zA-Z]+$/;
            var regEmail = /^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$/;
            if (namevalue.length == 0) { 
                alert("Please enter your name");    
                     return false; 
                    } 
                if(!regName.test(namevalue)){
                    alert('Invalid name given.');
                return false;   
                    }
            if (emailvalue.length == 0) {

                alert ("Please enter your email"); }

                if(!regEmail.test(emailvalue)){
                    alert("Please enter valid Email ID");
                        return false;
                }
            
            if (subjectvalue.length == 0) {
                alert ("Please enter the subject");
            
            }

            if (textvalue.length == 0) {
                alert ("Please enter some text");
            
            }
            if((namevalue.length != 0) && (emailvalue.length != 0) && (subjectvalue.length != 0) && (textvalue.length != 0)) {
                alert("Thank you for submitting")
                    return true;
            }
        }
    </script>
    
</head>
<body>
    <div style="background-color: lightblue; font-size: 25px; text-align: center; border: 4px solid blue;">
        <p>Contact Us</p>
    </div>
    <div style="background-color: lightblue; font-size: 15px; text-align: center; border: 4px solid blue;"> 
        <p>For any business inquires contact us</p>
    </div>
        <div><input type="text" value=" Full Name" id="textName" maxlength="100"/></div>
        <div><input type="text" value="Email" id="emailName"/></div>
        <div><input type="text" value="Subject" id="subjectName"/></div>
        <div><input type="text" value=Text id="importantName" style=”width:500px;height:50px;”></div>
        <input type="button" value="Click here" onclick="clickHere();"/>
        
    </div>
</body>
</hmtl>
```

Comment: Your next step is to investigate server side languages that work on your server. Once you determine the languages, I would then investigate how to send mail via that server side language. This isn't a function of pure client side (like Javascript).

Comment: You would need some server-side language to do this, like php. You can use the `mail` function in php to do what you need, if you decide to go with that and can follow this to add the functionality: https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mail_mail.asp

Answer (score 0):

As per comments, one way is setting up a server, which you can send the details to and it could email them on. I'd recommend looking into Node.js for this as it's javascript and avoids you having to learn another language.

Firebase is another solution, which would avoid having to set up a server. Look up Firebase Functions or search for a Firebase tutorial.

Finally, you could call a third-party Email API from your front-end code (SendGrid is one example). I would not recommend this approach in production because you would have to expose your API login details to all users, but it's an option if it's for fun.